# android app doesn't show the values from server

Tags: java, android

I have a CoAP server using the UDP port 5684 that receives values from arduino. When I run my Android app on the bluestacks emulator the values shows up, but when I run the same app on my cell phone (Samsung S4) it runs but the values didn't show.  Could any one tell me what is the problem?

Comment: Your Android phone may not be able to access the computer that the server is on. What computer is the server on? Is this IP address accessible from other computers on your network?

Comment: the server is on my laptop and yes if i use any other computer or laptop on the same network i can receive the value and i can see it (if  the same bluestacks emulator is used)

Comment: If you type in the servers IP address into a browser on your Android phone, what happens?

Comment: i type it, it gives me "this webpage is not available"

Comment: Yes it would say that actually if you do not have a web server running on your computer so that is not a valid test, my mistake. Are your emulator and server on the same machine? If so, are you using the correct address for your server in your app? For example, when running an app on an emulator, you typically use 10.0.2.2 to connect to the PC running the emulator. But when you deploy the app to a phone, you need to use the correct IP address of the server.

Comment: it is not a big deal thank you a lot; the emulator and the server are on the same machine but sometimes i run the emulator on a another laptop, and i use the real ip to connect to the server.

Comment: any ideas? i m still facing the same issue